# Apple Bluetooth keyboard is sometimes unresponsive, but becomes responsive again when Bluetooth -> Keyboard properties -> Services tab is opened

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

The Apple bluetooth wireless keyboard is installed on Windows, sometime it becomes unresponsive (meaning nothing that's typed in is received by the computer), but it becomes responsive again when I open the tab in Bluetooth Devices -> keyboard properties -> Services. Is there a solution to keep it responsive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Bluetooth wireless keyboard uses your Bluetooth adapter. Go to device manager, open the Properties menu of your Bluetooth adapter --> Power Management. Uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power." Then the keyboard shouldn't turn off again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first to fully patch your computer, also including optional updates in Windows Update.

Then find your keyboard in Device Manager,
right-click and choose Properties,
go to the Power Management tab and
uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

Comment: under keyboard, "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" was checked off by default. And my bluetooth device doesn't that that option.

Comment: Check in Control Panel / Power Option / Change plan settings / Change advanced power settings / Wireless Adapter Settings / Power Saving Mode. You may try to put it on Maximum Performance. If this doesn't help, maybe some other power setting may apply.

Comment: i've changed everything to "High Performance" keyboard sometimes is still unresponsive =(

Comment: Only additional advice I can think of is (1) ensure your drivers are up to date, (2) try another keyboard to see if this is a hardware problem.

Comment: (1) device driver is up to date (2) no other keyboard to test if it's hardware problem...